# Why can't I access the HasPicture property?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to manage contact objects with a C# application.

I'm loading the contacts with BindToItems:

```
ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> responses = service.BindToItems(itemIds, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
foreach (var responseItem in responses)
{
    contactDict.Add(responseItem.Item.Id, (Contact)responseItem.Item);
}
```

Then I try to check if the contact has changed by comparing its properties with my stored values.

```
         return exchangeContact.Surname != user.Surname
             || exchangeContact.CompanyName != user.Company
             ...
             || (!exchangeContact.HasPicture && user.ThumbnailPhoto != null)
```

But when I try to access the HasPicture property, an exception is thrown.

```
ServiceObjectPropertyException: This property was requested, but it wasn't returned by the server.
```

Checking in the debugger, this exception is also thrown for other properties of the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact`. Examples are:

- Birthday
- ContactSource
- IconIndex
- NormalizedBody
- TextBody
- PostalAddressIndex
- WeddingAnniversary

Why can't I access those properties? Are they not included in the FirstClassProperties? But [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567685(v=exchg.150).aspx) says that HasImage is a FirstClassProperty of Contact objects.

Comment: Did you checked if the account has a picture? if the account do not have a picture your "issue" might be expected.

Comment: The whole reason that I call the "HasPicture" property is to check if the account has a picture. I didn't know that that's not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from BastianW comment, you can check if the account has a picture by using the `Contact.TryGetProperty` method.

```
bool HasPicture;
exchangeContact.TryGetProperty(ContactSchema.HasPicture, out HasPicture);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem very intuitive that you can't check if the account has a picture by simply calling HasPicture. Your approach works and seems to be the intended way to do it.